# OfyService и PersistenceManager

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud

Какая разница между OfyService и PersistenceManager?
Изучаю примеры работы с App Engine и Endpoint. В одних примерах для работы с данными (сохранение) используют [PersistenceManager](https://github.com/branflake2267/DartRestWithJavaCloudEndpoints/blob/master/RestServerCloudEndpoints/src/org/gonevertical/server/endpoints/AnimalEndpoint.java), а в других [OfyService](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/blob/master/GcmEndpoints/root/src/main/RegistrationEndpoint.java.ftl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ взят от [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35780623/edit):

**PersistenceManager** is part of the [JDO (Java Data Objects)](https://db.apache.org/jdo/) library. It is the primary interface for JDO-aware application components.

> Java Data Objects (JDO) is a standard way to access persistent data in
>   databases, using plain old Java objects (POJO) to represent persistent
>   data. The approach separates data manipulation (done by accessing Java
>   data members in the Java domain objects) from database manipulation
>   (done by calling the JDO interface methods).

On the other hand **ObjectifyService** is part of [Objectify](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki) library. It is a provider of the thread-local Objectify instances.

> Objectify is a Java data access API specifically designed for the
>   Google Cloud Datastore.

Both libraries can be used to access Google Cloud Datastore, however, JDO is more generic and can be also used with other data stores.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/blob/master/GcmEndpoints/root/src/main/OfyService.java.ftl), the `OfyService` is just a custom wrapper for `ObjectifyService`.